# Describe the .NET assembly circular dependency problem in layman's terms

Tags: .net, assemblies, dependencies

Please describe the .NET assembly compilation circular dependency problem in layman's terms, and whether other technologes have similar limitations.

Note: This seems like a simple question, I know, but I have seen a number of real, significant projects that have totally broken dependency graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to Lucas's answer: it's very hard to come up with a circular *assembly* dependency in .NET. In order to compile `A.dll` you first need `B.dll`; to compile `B.dll` you first need `C.dll`; but to compile `C.dll` you need the `A.dll` you were trying to compile in the first place.

The only way you're likely to get into this situation is if you're developing A, B and C in parallel, and you've managed to introduce a circular dependency by accident. But as soon as you do a clean build of all three, the problem will be apparent, and you won't be able to proceed until you break the cycle.

Circular dependencies between namespaces and/or classes within a single dependency are a lot more common. I try to treat this kind of circular dependency as a code smell; a codebase without circular dependencies between components is one where those components can easily be kept separate and refactored independently.

Patrick Smacchia (the NDepend guy) talks a little about dependency cycles and their effect on code quality here: http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2009/07/29/maintainability-learnability-component-layering.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Same as any other circular dependency...

Consider three assemblies A, B & C

A needs something defined in B, B needs something defined in C, and C needs something defined in A.

Which can you build first?

Comment: You don't even need three - just A needs something in B and B needs something in A.

Comment: True enough.  I used three because two doesn't 'feel' circular, more like 'ping pong dependency' :)

Comment: Would it be possible to compile into an intermediate meta-assembly for splitting according to project right at the end of the compilation process?

Comment: @Ben Aston - It may be, but much better (IMO) would be to move things such that you don't have the circular dependency anymore.  If you add some details maybe we can help you with that (or ask it in a new question).

Comment: @Lucas, thanks. I am thinking hypothetically. I am interested in exploring to what extent the circular dependency limitation between assemblies in VS is artificial vs real.

Comment: @Ben Aston - Good deal.  In that case, it might be instructive for you to try and make a circular dependency in a little throw away project and then refactor it out.

Comment: @Lucas - I have created said project and played with programmatic circular dependencies too. It just seemed that the circular dependency dialog in VS is merely using the simple heuristic of "A refs B, so B cannot ref A", as opposed to examining the code to see if an issue really exists - or whether it would even be possible to implement a compiler in such a fashion as to attempt compilation using my aforementioned intermediate compilation step.

Answer (score 0):

I am one of the developer of the tool [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/Res/NDependWhiteBook_Assembly.pdf) for .NET developers that is specialized in enforcing clean  code structure and remove dependency cycles. On our product site you'll find [two white-books](http://www.ndepend.com/WhiteBooks.aspx) relative to the component dependency cycle issue:

[Partitioning code base through .NET assemblies and Visual Studio projects](http://www.ndepend.com/Res/NDependWhiteBook_Assembly.pdf) (8 pages)

- Common valid and invalid reasons to create an assembly
- Increase Visual Studio solution compilation performance (up to x10 faster)
- Organize the development environment

[Defining .NET Components with Namespaces](http://www.ndepend.com/Res/NDependWhiteBook_Namespace.pdf) (7 pages)

- Defining components inside .NET assemblies
- **Acyclic graph** of dependencies between components
- Evolutionary Design and **Acyclic componentization**