# How to Access members of WPF App & ClassLibrary and vice versa

Tags: wpf, class, mvvm

I am into this wpf from last 2 weeks. I am currently developing a wpf application based on MVVM pattern. I have 2 projects inside my Solution in Visual C# 2010. One is a WPF application(lets say MSPBoardControl) and other is a Class Library(lets say ConnectViewComponent). Thus both the MSPBoardControl and ConnectViewComponent have the view, viewmodel, model classes respectively.

I have added the reference of ConnectViewComponent in my MSPBoardControl and I am able to access the member variables of ConnectViewComponent in my MSPBoardControl's View,Viewmodel and model class. My concern is how to access the member variables of MSPBoardControl from my ConnectViewComponent.

**ViewModel of MSPBoardControl:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using ConnectViewComponent.Model;
using System.Windows.Input;
using ConnectViewComponent.Commands;
[[[using MSPBoardControl.ViewModel;]]]

namespace ConnectViewComponent.ViewModel
{
public class ConnectViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public List<ConnectModel> m_BoardNames;
    [[[BoardControlViewModel mBoardVM;]]]

    public ConnectViewModel()
    {
        m_BoardNames = new List<ConnectModel>()
        {                
            new ConnectModel() {Name = "Bavaria", Connection_Status = "Disconnected"},
            new ConnectModel() {Name = "Redhook", Connection_Status = "Disconnected"},                
        };
    }

    public List<ConnectModel> BoardNames
    {
        //get set
    }

    private ConnectModel m_SelectedBoardItem;
    public ConnectModel SelectedBoard
    {
        //get set
    }

    private ICommand mUpdater;
    public ICommand ConnectCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (mUpdater == null)
                mUpdater = new DelegateCommand(new Action(SaveExecuted), new Func<bool>(SaveCanExecute));

            return mUpdater;
        }
        set
        {
            mUpdater = value;
        }
    }

    public bool SaveCanExecute()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void SaveExecuted()
    {
        if (SelectedBoard.Connection_Status == "Disconnected" && SelectedBoard.Name == "Bavaria")
        {
            SelectedBoard.Connection_Status = "Connected";                
        }

        else if (SelectedBoard.Connection_Status == "Disconnected" && SelectedBoard.Name == "Redhook")
        {
            SelectedBoard.Connection_Status = "Connected";               
        }
    }
}
}
```

[[[ -- ]]] in my code denotes I am not able to access the members of BoardControlViewModel as well as USING Namespace.ViewModel too.

I cannot add the reference of BoardControl in my ConnectComponent project since it will lead to circular dependency. How can I access it? Please Help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having circular dependencies in your project can be a "code smell". There are various ways to remove this "smell". For simplicity lets say that you have project A and project B that has a circular dependency.

1. Factor out the common types used by both projects and move them into a new project C. Let A and B reference C. This should remove either the dependency from A to B or the opposite dependency or even both dependencies.
2. If A and B has types that need to interact you need to decouple this interaction into a common set of abstractions (e.g. interfaces or abstract base classes). You should then move these types without any implementation into project C that both A and B references. This will allow the types in A and B to interact but only using the definitions in C. An example could be that A is the main application. It calls in interface `IService` defined in C but implemented in B and registers a callback `IServiceCallback` defined in C via `IService`. B can then call back into A using `IServiceCallback` without knowing that the implementation is in A.
3. If the types in A and B are strongly coupled you should merge A and B into a single project.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Looking at the coupling, I think i shud merge A & B into a single project :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a some type of "Common" library (project) that will contain those general classes. So both BoardControl and ConnectComponent can reference it.

Also you can check [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304278/describe-the-net-assembly-circular-dependency-problem-in-laymans-terms).

Comment: I need to access only the Viewmodel class of both the projects. A's viewmodel With B's vm and vice versa. They are dependent on each other :)